# Terraform: AWS Cloudfront distribution gives CNAMEAlreadyExists error after changing terraform state backend from local to s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, devops, terraform

I'm trying out terraform to set up an S3 + Cloudfront static site. Initially, I set up the site successfully, following the steps from https://alimac.io/static-websites-with-s3-and-hugo-part-1/

However, afterwards I changed the terraform state backend from `local` to `s3` Now, when I perform `terraform apply` I get the following error:

```
Error: Error applying plan:

2 error(s) occurred:

* aws_cloudfront_distribution.primary_domain: 1 error(s) occurred:

* aws_cloudfront_distribution.primary_domain: CNAMEAlreadyExists: One or more of the CNAMEs you provided are already associated with a different resource.
    status code: 409, request id: <removed>
* aws_cloudfront_distribution.secondary_domain: 1 error(s) occurred:

* aws_cloudfront_distribution.secondary_domain: CNAMEAlreadyExists: One or more of the CNAMEs you provided are already associated with a different resource.
    status code: 409, request id: <removed>
```

Any ideas about why this might be happening and what can I do to fix this issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Terraform uses the state file to keep track of resources it manages. If it does not have a particular resource (in this case probably your `aws_cloudfront_distribution.primary_domain` resource), it will create a new one and store the ID of that new resource in your state file.

It looks like you did a `terraform apply` with your local state file, changed the backend to s3 without porting the state to s3, then ran `terraform apply` again. This second S3-backed run has a blank state, so it tried to recreate your `aws_cloudfront_distribution` resources again. Looks like the error [indicates a conflict in using the same CNAME for two distributions](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/resolve-cnamealreadyexists-error/), which is what would happen if you ran Terraform twice without keeping track of state in between.

You have a couple of options to fix this:

- Go back to using your existing local state file, `terraform destroy`
  to remove the resources it created, switch back to s3, then
  `terraform apply` to start anew. Be aware that this will actually
  delete resources.
- Properly change your backend and [reinitialize](https://www.terraform.io/docs/backends/config.html#changing-configuration), then answer "yes" to copying your remote state to S3.
- `terraform import` the resources you created with your local state file into your S3 backend. Do this with `terraform import
  aws_cloudfront_distribution.primary_domain <EXISTING CLOUDFRONT DIST.
  ID>`.

Comment: Thanks, I figured out that the issue was indeed that the local state was lost, leading to attempted creation of new aws resources. Thankfully I had manually backed up my local state file before the attempted switch to s3. So, a restore of the old local state file + proper re-initialization of the S3 backend resulted in a proper terraform based deploy. I've documented these steps at https://github.com/agrimprasad/terraform-s3/blob/master/README.md